If by-election is held close to the general elections is the seat contested again?
In the UK, if by-election is held close to the general elections, is then the seat contested again? Has the by-election winning candidate, the elected MP, stand for election again, just few months later?
I suspect the answer is - yes. They have to do it again.
If it is like that - it's brutal on the candidates. The election campaign must be physically and mentally exhaustive, stressful and costly. And for what? Just to it again few months later, and possibly lose?
Bonus question:
Are candidates and elected MPs somewhat compensated for standing in by-elections close to the general elections?
UPDATE:
I've moved my supposed answer to the more appropriate answer section, as was kindly pointed out to me.
UPDATE 2:
By-elections in UK can happen only in a very specific situations, that should be outside of control of any political party, and therefore are relatively rare:
Quoting https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/by-elections/:

A by-election is held when a seat becomes vacant. This can happen when an MP:

resigns or dies
is declared bankrupt
takes a seat in the House of Lords
is subject to a successful recall petition
is convicted of a serious criminal offence.

A by-election does not have to take place if an MP changes political party.


You start off asking "is a seat contested again if there was a by-election just a few months before", then provide multiple examples proving that's the case, then switch at the end to asking a completely different question. If the latter question is what you actually want to know about, then I suggest editing the question to focus on it, rather than burying it inside a completely different question.

If standing in a byelection meant not having to contest your seat in a general election for a while, sitting governments would intentionally trigger by-elections in some seats, in order to win them a few months before they call a general election and before their opponents start their election campaigns. There is no "compensation" for an MP whose term is shortened by an earlier-than-expected general election, because being elected as an MP is not meant to be a reward for the individual MP, it is meant to be an act of public service.

@kaya3 I don't think sitting government can trigger by-elections in any official/legal way (apart from murder; or somehow forcing him to resign, how?).
During by-elections all candidates should have same opportunity to do their campaigns like in general elections.

Please don't add bonus questions to other related questions but ask them separately. That way we can better deal with them individually.

I suspect the answer is - yes. They have to do it again.
Two examples:
https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/by-elections/by-elections-2019/
1)
Blackpool South, by-elections held on 2 May 2024, Chris Webb won. Just a month before general election!
And he seems to be re-elected (?) again.
https://members.parliament.uk/constituencies?SearchText=Blackpool+South
2)
Rochdale, by-elections held on 29 February 2024, George Galloway won.
And he was not re-elected in June.
https://members.parliament.uk/constituencies?SearchText=Rochdale
Labour's Paul Waugh is MP there now.

If the date of a general election is already known when a seat becomes vacant, filling it is usually delayed to the general election, to save repeated elections. This didn't happen for your example because the general election was called unexpectedly by Rishi Sunak.

To expand a bit on the previous comment, by convention the motion to call a by-election is made by the chief whip of the party which previously held the seat (or the government if it was an independent) q.v. https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/by-elections/ The opposition will not know the timing of a surprise election, and in 2024 even most Conservatives weren't aware.

The best examples are the New Forest and Barkston Ash by-elections in 1905. Parliament didn’t sit between those by-elections and the subsequent general election, so the winning candidates never took up their seats and became MPs, but the seats were still contested in the general election, and both the by-election winners lost.
